# How can I calculate desired selling price based on margin?

Tags: percentages, percentile

I use the following formula to calculate profit margin:

$$\text{profit_margin} = \frac{\text{selling_price} - (0.15\cdot \text{selling_price}) - \text{sourcing_cost}}{\text{sourcing_cost}}$$

What would the formula for $\text{selling_price}$ look like if the $\text{profit_margin}=0.3$ and the $\text{sourcing_cost}=16$?

Thank you

Comment: Substitute the values for the variables.  What are you asking?

Comment: I'm having issues with moving the selling_cost variable to one side to calculate it based on specified profit margin and sourcing cost.

Comment: Write down what you have done so far **in the body of the question**, so we can see where you are having problems.  You won't get much help unless you show your work.

Comment: Sorry about that but its there already: profit_margin = (selling_price - (0.15 * selling_price) - sourcing cost) / sourcing cost
What should I do next? Multiply both sides by selling_price to get rid of it in the denominator?

Comment: You mean you haven't done *anything* with the $.3$ and the $16?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine selling prices to get $$\frac{\text{selling_price} - (0.15\cdot \text{selling_price}) - \text{sourcing_cost}}{\text{sourcing_cost}}=\frac{0.85\cdot\text{selling_price}- \text{sourcing_cost}}{\text{sourcing_cost}}$$
then multiply both sides of your equation by the denominator and rearrange for the selling price.